# how to configure a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I've a Maven plugin which needs to be included in multiple git repos.

is there any way to provide plugin definition at one place and use it in multiple projects?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can define it in a parent pom...and use that parent pom...

Comment: @khmarbaise this won't work. I'll have to include all the children in parent pom. Which i don't want. My plugin processes all the modules of a project and if I create parent the way you suggested it will process all the repos  together.

Comment: This is simply wrong. You can create separate standalone parent pom which contains the configuration / setup and other configuration and version fixes for plugins... A parent does not imply defining modules (called multi module build).

Comment: Sure, let me try. Will get back.